# How to merge/insert values from column2 table1, to column2 table2, at the corresponding ID

Tags: sql, oracle

Started with SQL today. Read about Merging with updating, inserting etc. Wondering what's the correct (efficient) way to do it now trying to do the following:

```
Table1
+-------+------+   
| L_ID  | N_D  |
| 1700  | 21   |
| 1400  | 1    |
| 2400  | 1    |
| 1500  | 1    |
| 1800  | 1    |
| 2500  | 1    |
| 2700  | 1    |
+-------+------+

Table2
+-------+------+   
| L_ID  | N_D  |
| 1000  | -    |
| 1100  | -    |
| 1200  | -    |
| 1300  | -    |
| 1400  | -    |
| 1500  | -    |
| 1600  | -    |
+-------+------+
```

The N_D values from table1 should be inserted the corresponding L_ID of table2, if there's no match it should insert a 0.

My current piece of code for this follows, but throws an error `ORA-00911: invalid character`

```
MERGE INTO Table2 x
USING (SELECT L_ID, N_D FROM Table1) y
ON (x.L_ID = L_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET x.N_D = y.N_D
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     x.N_D = 0
```

Comment: Seams like a missing alias ? `ON (x.L_ID = L_ID)` -> `ON (x.L_ID = y.L_ID)` ?  But @GordonLinoff is right a simple co-related update seams to better suited for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `update`:

```
update table2 t2
    set n_d = coalesce( (select t1.n_db from table1 t1 where t1.l_id = t2.l_id), 0);
```

Comment: You're choosing x.n_d, in this case is it t2.n_d? And after the select, y.n_db, it's y.n_d? perhaps I'm meant to initialise the x and y with the first table reference?

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for updating it. when you select t1 from table t1, is there a way to reference table1 to t1 before calling t1.n_d? because it throws "T1"."N_D": invalid identifier, i suspect because t1 isn't initialised?

Comment: @van . . . `t1` is defined as an alias for `table1`.  It should be recognized.

Comment: thanks, i was referencing a wrong table, sorry about that!